# Font-weight not changing in css

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet, webfonts, google-webfonts

Using a google webfont, I can't get the font-weight to yield results. The three weights do have names but aren't specified in the href link so I'm not sure if the name needs to be added.

Here's that portion of the code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44K2M/1/

Comment: I've tried testing the page in both Safari and Firefox and neither will change the weight. The font itself renders fine though.

Comment: Just if you care (don't say you should): This is **way** too less info to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

:- Use preconnect in relation before link any type of extronal font now it is  work if any problem then told me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in a fiddle which leads me to believe you have another font-weight overriding the font-weight you are trying to set. Use either chrome or Firefox's developer tools and you can easily locate the style that is overriding the one you are trying to set.

Keep in mind:

1. More specific styles win (ID vs class for example)
2. Styles found later in the style sheet will override identical styles earlier in the sheet.